# Can't get a server to recognize and load the osgi from updateSite.nsf

Tags: xpages, osgi-bundle

I have imported both the openNTF extension library and the BootStrap library into my updateSte.nsf and that all looks OK with version 9.0.1.v00_11_20141217-1000 for the extension Library and 1.0.0.201407020945 for the Bootstrap Library. I have added in the server config OSGI_HTTP_DYNAMIC_BUNDLES=UpdateSiteEXT.nsf

then tell HTTP restart

tell HTTP osgi ss org.openntf.bootstrap

does not list any packages

tell HTTP osgi ss org.openntf.extlib

likewise does not list any packages

tell HTTP osgi ss com.ibm.extlib

and I get a list of the ibm extension libraries.

I have this working on another server but can't seem to get it to work on a new server. Am I missing something?

Some further information:
I deleted the original updatesite DB.
I created a new updatesite.nsf and imported the openntf extLib site and the bootstrap and that looks fine. I signed the DB with the active Server ID.
Changed the configuration to point to updatesite.nsf using the configuration in the server document
Shut down server and check that the Notes.ini was in fact pointing to the correct DB - it was.
restarted the server and the log looks like this:

```
14/01/2015 10:34:59 AM  HTTP Server: Using Web Configuration View
14/01/2015 10:34:59 AM  AMgr: Executive '1' started. Process id '4248'
14/01/2015 10:35:06 AM  Domino OSGi Tasklet Container started ( profile DOTS )
14/01/2015 10:35:07 AM  JVM: Java Virtual Machine initialized.
14/01/2015 10:35:07 AM  HTTP Server: Java Virtual Machine loaded
14/01/2015 10:35:07 AM  HTTP Server: DSAPI Domino Off-Line Services HTTP extension Loaded successfully
14/01/2015 10:35:07 AM  [DOTS] (UpdateWidgetsTask) CLFWW2200I: Running iNotes Widget automatic update.
14/01/2015 10:35:07 AM  [DOTS] (UpdateWidgetsTask) CLFWW2201W: There is no iNotes Widget automatic update group configured. Update will not run.
14/01/2015 10:35:07 AM  [DOTS] (UpdateWidgetsTask) CLFWW2203I: iNotes Widget automatic update has finished.
14/01/2015 10:35:19 AM  XSP Command Manager initialized
14/01/2015 10:35:20 AM  HTTP Server: Started
```

> tell http osgi ss org.openntf.extlib
>   14/01/2015 11:12:21 AM  Framework is launched.
>   14/01/2015 11:12:21 AM  id  State       Bundle
>
> tell http osgi ss org.openntf.bootstrap
>   14/01/2015 11:13:07 AM  Framework is launched.
>   14/01/2015 11:13:07 AM  id  State       Bundle
>
> tell http osgi ss com.ibm.xsp.extlib
>   14/01/2015 11:13:49 AM  Framework is launched.
>   14/01/2015 11:13:49 AM  id  State       Bundle
>   14/01/2015 11:13:49 AM  91  <>    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls_9.0.1.v00_00_20140801-1000
>   14/01/2015 11:13:49 AM  92  <>    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.core_9.0.1.v00_00_20140801-1000
>   14/01/2015 11:13:49 AM  93  <>    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.domino_9.0.1.v00_00_20140801-1000
>   14/01/2015 11:13:49 AM  94  <>    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.mobile_9.0.1.v00_00_20140801-1000
>   14/01/2015 11:13:49 AM  95  <>    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.oneui_9.0.1.v00_00_20140801-1000
>   14/01/2015 11:13:49 AM  96  <>    com.ibm.xsp.extlib_9.0.1.v00_00_20140801-1000

I removed a few lines that are not relevant to this issue. I do not see any reference to the loading of the osgi but the task did start. It loaded the com.ibm.xsp.extlib but not the org.openntf.ext nor org.openntf.bootstrap which appear to be properly loaded in the updatesite.nsf I can run the tell http osgi ss com.ibm.xsp.extlib and get the proper list but get nothing for the org.openntf.extlib not the bootstrap. They just looks as if the boot process is ignoring the load from updatesite.nsf.

Have done a full server restart every time! updatesite.nsf signed by the active server ID and I have signed the content, I'm the Admin of the server with all rights.

This is really weird because I have it working on another server in the same Org. I should not have to make changes anywhere else should I? I've got to be missing something fairly simple but no idea what.

Comment: FYI the list of extlib plugins you've got there from the `tell http osgi ss com.ibm.xsp.extlib` is the ones that are part of the 9.0.1 GA, not release 11 of the extlib. So nothing from the update site is getting loaded. For example `com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls_9.0.1.v00_00_` would read `com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls_9.0.1.v00_11_` for release 11 version of the plugin. Not sure why the update site isn't loading for you though

Comment: Brian - that is my whole point nothing is getting loaded and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All though I had signed the content of the update site with my ID the problem was that this was a new server install and the Security settings in the Server Document Names.nsf had not been set. When I added my Notes_Admin group to the security Programmabilty Restrictions it now loads correctly. Was looking everywhere but the obvious.
I'm now a happy camper.

Answer (score 5):

I think after setting the notes.ini variable you need to do a full server restart, not just a restart of HTTP.

Also, `tell http restart` doesn't reload the JVM. You need to do `restart task http` to fully restart HTTP.

Comment: Most frustrating. I uninstalled the Domino Server and got rid of all the files and did a complete new install. Made a new SiteUpdate.nsf and imported the lates Extension Library and BootStrap. Signed them with my ID (I'm admin) added the path to the UpdateSite.nsf to the ini. Shut down the server and did a cold reboot. On start up there are no errors. if on the server I "tell http osgi ss extlib" I get the list of just the core IBM extLib files, likewise "tell http osgi ss bootstrap" only lists the basic IBM bootstrap. I'm lost! The server works fine but only have the basic IBM modules.

Comment: One time I've seen nothing from an update site getting picked up was because the notes.ini variable was wrong. I don't know how to test that though. Otherwise, Per's suggestion of signer and authority to run code might be another cause.

Answer (score 2):

Try restarting your server as Paul says. Also make sure that the update site AND the content is signed. You sign the content from within the update site nsf.

Comment: The update site database is a replica copy from another server in the same Org, do you need a different update site for each server?

Comment: I don't think so, Bill. But I've never tried using a replica.

Answer (score 1):

...and not to forget: if you added a "new" updatesite to your notes.ini you have to restart the whole server for it to recognize the new path ;-)

Answer (score 0):

We also had issues with OSGI plugins that are not activating. We solved them by signing the updateesite using the action in the menu(not the signing method from the admin client)

Answer (score 0):

Like user2316219, what worked for me was using the "Actions\Sign All Content" option from within the Update Site database.  Signing the database - even using the "Content" option - from the Admin Client did not work.  And then, of course, tell http quit, load http.

Slight twist to my problem as well.  Tell OSGI showed that some components from the OpenNTF ExtLib were loaded from the updatesite, but the core extlib library being loaded was an older version from the Domino install.  So OSGI seemed to be selectively loading components.